# How do I keep reading data from my Socket to append my buffer

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, sockets, tcp

So I'm trying to send an image from my client to my server and I'm sending the entire image as a whole, meaning that I'm not splitting it up into chunks, I'm just sending the entire byte array as is.

**CLIENT**

```
private void SendImage(byte[] opcode, byte[] length, byte[] payload)
{
    var packet = new byte[payload.Length + length.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(opcode, 0, packet, 0, 1);

    //Set the length
    Array.Copy(length, 0, packet, 1, length.Length);


    Array.Copy(payload, 0, packet, 5, payload.Length);
    _clientSocket.Send(packet);
}
```

This sends just fine, I'm using the OpCode `0x15` which will be interpreted by the server as "there is an image incoming". The length is the `payload.Length` which I've done this with

`var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(myImage.Length);`

So it occupies 4 bytes.

So my packet structure looks like this `OpCode(1 byte), Length(4 bytes), Payload(imageBytes)`

This method works just fine, it sends without any issues what so ever, I only included the code for it so that the next part will make sense.

**SERVER**

```
private byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    int received = client.EndReceive(ar);

    //Temporary buffer
    var dataBuf = new byte[received];
    Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);

    
    switch (dataBuf[0])
    {
        //Received image
        case 0x15:
            //Read the packet header and check the length of the payload
            var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataBuf.Skip(1).Take(4).ToArray(), 0);

            //This will hold the bytes for the image
            var imageBuffer = new byte[length];

            //First incoming packet payload (image bytes)
            var imgData = dataBuf.Skip(5).ToArray();

            //Copy that into the buffer
            Array.Copy(imgData, 0, imageBuffer, 0, imgData.Length);


            var pos = imgData.Length;
            //Keep reading bytes from the incoming stream
            while (dataBuf.Length > 0)
            {
                imgData = new byte[1024];
                client.Receive(imgData);
                Array.Copy(imgData, 0, imageBuffer, pos, dataBuf.Length);
                pos += 1024;
            }

            //This takes the bytes and creates a bitmap from it
            AnotherViewModel.SetImage(imageBuffer);
            break;

        default:
            Debug.WriteLine("Wat");
            break;
    }

    client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), client);

}
```

The issues I'm facing is that I don't know how to keep appending the incoming data to the `imageBuffer` because I want to receive the full image and not just the first 4 bytes and with my while loop I'm currently getting this exception

> Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and
> the array's lower bounds.

Over at this line `Array.Copy(imgData, 0, imageBuffer, pos, dataBuf.Length);`

How do I properly read the entire image that the client sends to the server?

Comment: You might need to check how many bytes you are actually receiving, you seem to be assuming that it's a perfect multiple of 1024, which might not be the case. the pos variable should only be incremented by the actually received length rather than 1024 (the max size). My spider senses are telling me that it's the last block that gets you in trouble.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but you might need to design a better comm protocol. Counting bytes on network streams is not good, in my humble opinion. Check out how FTP works. The fact that you send the whole image in client does not guarantee it will arrive like this at the server. It certainly will be fragmented all the way down and up the tcpip stack.
The server is receiving asynchronously, so I'm guessing the code in the ReceiveCallback is called many times. It's the wrong place to read some bytes and switch accordingly.